# Word for someone who acts like an expert but who has very little knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What is a word to describe an individual who acts like an expert in a subject area, constantly stating facts and correcting people, but who actually has very little knowledge on the subject?

Comment: @Robusto: I assume you're thinking the difference is *this* one specifically mentions *actually has very little knowledge on the subject*. But the top answer on what I see as the "original" does actually say ***know-it-all** has a slightly negative connotation to it, because it implies that the person really doesn't know it all.* And [I've been specifically advised](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/) *not* to refrain from closevoting simply because my rep for one of the tags means my vote will be unilaterally applied. Just following orders, guv! :)

Comment: This question addresses the 'bluffing' sense, unlike the non-dupe.

Comment: @Fumble: Interestingly enough, about half an hour before you closed this, [the person who specifically advised you not to stint on CVs](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/) himself cast the slam-close vote [and then rescinded it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23597222#23597222). In any case, this one adds the element of hypocrisy, which your proposed canonical does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word for someone ignorant of, but not expected to be knowledgeable about, something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251797/word-for-someone-ignorant-of-but-not-expected-to-be-knowledgeable-about-someth)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That is not really a duplicate. The one you suggest requires the quality of no expectation (by others) of knowing anything, whereas this one requires that the person behave in a manner to lead people to believe the opposite.

Comment: @Robusto I dunno, I think any of the answers posted so far are appropriate and could answer the "original" question. But there is an implied caveat which requires the term to be somewhat obscure, unusual, archaic, rare = "Word of the day". A *poseur*, for example,  is none of those things.

Comment: I had some trouble finding the possible duplicate everyone is talking about.  I'll post it here to make it easier for others reading this page.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97604/an-idiom-to-describe-someone-who-thinks-he-she-is-wiser-than-others

Comment: All the answers so far (except perhaps tchrist’s, which I haven't quite deciphered yet) seem to assume that you are talking about someone who _deliberately and falsely_ represent themselves as being experts while fully aware they are not—‘cheating’, as it were. This doesn't seem to be part of the question as it is worded, though. Are you asking about people like that specifically, or equally about people who themselves _think_ they are experts on something, but objectively seen know little about it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with you--there's a difference between knowingly doing something (a fraud, pretender or charlatan) and someone who unknowingly does something (a fool or ignoramus.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet An ultracrepidarian is unaware that he has given advice on matters above his expertise (hence the name), and the morosoph is as clueless about his own foolishness as any other sophomore.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was looking for someone who is unconsciously doing so, perhaps as a result of enthusiasm, and not someone who is being deliberately 'cheating'. Perhaps I should have added more context

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## *Cryptonescient Morosophs* and *Ultracrepidarians*

The *cryptonescient* are best described as *morosophs* and *ultracrepidarians*,
as any philodox or sumpsimus
drawn
into this epeolatrous logomachy
like a saturniïd to a pharol
will deliciate in apprising you with all due impigrity.

Those epithets you may freely employ
safe from all risk of nettling
even the most inveterate of doryphores,
for even if this should fail to deliver the recumbentibus you’re looking for,
it should at least jargogle
your nemetic opsimath
long enough for you to avolate undetected
under the supervenient obnubilation.

Comment: Come again? Could you link all those fancy words to dictionary references, please.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Could it be he's providing a working example of the creature described in the OP? Just asking...

Comment: No, our lad tchrist knows his stuff. I just didn't find definitions for *all* the weird and wonderful words that are crammed in this post, using Chrome dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I could, but linking to the OED does little good to unsubscribers. Just double-click the word to highlight it, ring-click to pull up a menu, and then select whichever menu item your own browser uses for looking things up or googling them.

Comment: For example for *philodox*, chrome dictionary brings up *werewolf*, which is weird. And my browser dictionary gives up on *pharol*. I shall have to google them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA OED: ***“philodox*** /ˈfɪlədɒks/. *rare.* Etymology: ad. Gr. *φιλόδοξ-ος* adj. (Plato), loving fame or glory, f. *φιλο-* philo- + *δόξα* glory (also opinion, etc.). Properly, One who loves fame or glory; but taken (after *orthodox*) as = One who loves his own opinion; an argumentative or dogmatic person. So *philoˈdoxical* a.”

Comment: For those who care: [*pharol*](http://findwords.info/term/pharol); [*impigrity*](http://findwords.info/term/impigrity) and [*recumbentibus*](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-rec1.htm)

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Farol* is a normal word in Spanish, which is why I knew it, and figures in many old songs. Faro is also a Portuguese city in the Algarve named for its lighthouse. All derive from the Greek.

Comment: You had me until 'obnubilation'. That just didn't make sense.

Comment: I recognized a good number of those words.

Comment: "Ultracrepidarian" seems to fit what I had in mind, thanks!

Comment: Hang on… _saturnid_? One i?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Depends how you want to to anglicize the Latin family name *Saturniidae* (which indeed has two *i*’s).  Most sources speak of *Saturnid moths* with just one *i*, and that is the form I learned as a child.

Comment: Hmm… well, I’ve never seen it before (granted, I don’t read much about moths), and [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=saturnid+moth%2Csaturniid+moth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaturnid%20moth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaturniid%20moth%3B%2Cc0) has the double-i’ed version as more common. A simple Google search also gives about 35,000 for _“saturniid moth”_ and less than 5,000 for _“saturnid moth”_. The OED doesn’t have _saturnid_ at all (no hits in COCA for either). Perhaps a regional thing? I assume it’s trisyllabic for you too?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It’s probably because I was brought up on [the Peterson field guide](https://goo.gl/ijdVwS), which has the single-*i* spelling. But yes, it has three syllables for me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh very well, I’ll give it its double-*i* — suitably diæ̈reticked. :)

Answer (score 13):

Charlatan = a person who pretends or claims to have more knowledge or skill than he or she possesses; quack.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/charlatan

Comment: This was incorrect in the duplicate-or-is-it, but works well here.

Comment: FYI, the duplicate-or-is-it link Edwin mentioned: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97604/an-idiom-to-describe-someone-who-thinks-he-she-is-wiser-than-others

Comment: Thanks; this link was posted earlier, when a member thought mistakenly that this was a duplicate. But that's totally different. Someone who acts like (s)he's smarter than everyone else versus someone who acts like an expert in a particular field.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like a [poseur](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poseur) (M-W),

> a person who pretends to be what he or she is not

In this case, posing as a knowledgeable person.

Answer (score 6):

The word *dilettante* might work. Dilettante is used to describe an amateur who pretends to be very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's a bit general and broad in meaning, my suggestion is *[pretender](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretender)*:

- a person who pretends, especially for a dishonest purpose.
- a person who makes unjustified or false claims, statements, etc., as    about personal status, abilities, intentions, or the like

For example:

> Could he pretend to be a doctor? He knew a fair bit, from Cathy's pregnancies, her motorcycle accident, his father's stroke, Suzie's addictions. (from *Under the Skin* by Michel Faber)

Answer (score 3):

*Fraud*. This is a very good word.

Comment: Good answer, but you could improve it with a definition and exxample.

Answer (score 3):

**Bluffer**

From *bluff*, "to impress, deter, or intimidate by a false display of confidence"

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition

Also, I'm not sure if

**know-it-all**

was explicitly proposed for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Such a person could be described as an *armchair expert* or *armchair pundit*.

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/armchair):

> [as modifier] Lacking or not involving practical or direct experience of a particular subject or activity: *an armchair traveller*

Example sentences:

> The result is a unique perspective applauded by *armchair naturalists* in which the stars of the film are also the videographers.
>
> What do these *armchair counter-terrorists* propose that Moscow should have done?
>
> Almost all other commentary was grotesque - the work of *armchair generals*.

See also this article: '[Edward Sapir was not an "armchair linguist"!](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2622)'