# Is "prayerlike" a word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, dictionaries

It's included the Merriam-Webster dictionary.
I'm just curious if it is acknowledged as a proper form of "prayer."

Comment: "Prayerlike" means "resembling a prayer".  It's not a form of prayer.  And, yes, it's a perfectly valid word.

Comment: @HotLicks the question asks «form of "prayer"», not «form of prayer».

Comment: related: [what does the phrase “a real word” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268623/what-does-the-phrase-a-real-word-mean)

Comment: @hobbs - OK, if Opie is asking whether it's a "form" of the word "prayer" (like "going" is a form of the word "go"), no.  It is a compound word, formed of the two words "prayer" and "like".  "Like" can be fairly freely appended to nouns (eg, "humanlike") to form adjectives meaning "resembling a <noun>" (though there is often an argument as to whether a hyphen should be inserted).

Comment: Acknowledged by whom? What is a proper form? What is a "prayer" in quotation marks? The question is unclear. Edit it to clarify what it is you are after.

Answer (score 1):

English, unlike other languages does not have a central authority on what is and what isn't valid. Since it lacks this, we can use two criteria to determine if it is a word: whether major dictionaries such as Merriam-Webster or Oxford list it, and whether people use it. Merriam-Webster is the only dictionary that lists it as a word. As for whether it is a real word, we can check how frequently it's used. According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prayerlike%2Cprayer-like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprayerlike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprayer%20-%20like%3B%2Cc0), *prayerlike* and *prayer-like* are currently used at roughly the same frequency. Since it is used as frequently as an alternative form and listed by a major dictionary, we can conclude that *prayerlike* is a word.

Comment: OED doesn't list it because *-like* is a productive suffix and if it included all words ending in *-like* it would would be even huger than it is already. *Antlike, benchlike, catlike, doglike...*