# Gender neutral alternative to Sir/Madam

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral, gender-politics, hailnames, social-gender

This question has been asked on this website before—but [one example was closed as off topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125375/dear-sir-or-madam-when-gender-unknown), and [the other specifically regarded use in a letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/dear-sir-or-madam-versus-to-whom-it-may-concern).

My context requires the use of speech, as if you worked in a call center—where the caller's voice may not give an indication of their gender. Also, gender-neutral terms are often preferred these days.

Where you need to treat the customer with respect—what  alternative to Sir or Madam can be used?

Comment: Related:[“Mx” the gender-neutral honorific](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285796/mx-the-gender-neutral-honorific)

Comment: Same question: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/what-are-appropriate-gender-agnostic-alternatives-to-sir-maam

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100598/discussion-on-question-by-dwjohnston-gender-neutral-alternative-to-sir-madam).

Comment: This question is completely lacking in any research and should not have been reopened.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly enough being in the military, especially saluting officers we say "Good morning, Sir" or "Good morning, Ma'am".

But at the same time I was thinking the other day about people of different genders or females that look more masculine and vice versa. What do I say then?

Simply put, just say "Good morning". Leave out the gender. Play it safe.

Comment: This reminded me that in some fiction it's proposed that elimination of the distinction is at least plausible.  In these works military superiors of any gender are addressed the same―usually as *sir*. One example is *Battlestar Galactica*.

Answer (score 4):

There are few gender neutral honorifics in English that are going to sound completely natural in a conversational context, especially a call center.

If unwilling to work around the matter as others have suggested this may be a case where you could experiment with setting precedent for new cultural norms.

I have, on occasion, used the phrase *my friend* for this situation. However, that may be taken as too familiar depending on the circumstances.  For example, I am quite put off when a politician with whom I have no other relationship addresses me as "my friend." Or even if this is done collectively as "my friends" when I am part of his audience. Yuck.

Hotels in their writing sometimes use the expression *honored guest*. Businesses more generally might adopt *valued customer*, *esteemed patron* and so on.

There's no grammatical reason these written forms of address can't be impressed into verbal service.  And that they sound strange is largely a matter of becoming accustomed to them.

Comment: But Orwell expressly instructs us that sounding outlandish is even worse than being ungrammatical, so sounding strange must be seen as not very advisable. Your esteemed patron might perhaps vote with their feet to a less eccentrically staffed  hotel.

Answer (score 2):

In spoken English for answering a call in a call center, you can avoid a gendered address simply by using repectful tone of voice and slightly formal phrasing:
     "Thank you for your call.  How may I help you today?" 
                                       or 
     "Would you please reboot your machine?"
                                       vs.
     "What can I do for you, sir?"
                                       or 
     "What do you need, ma'am?"

In written English for a call center situation such as emailing a customer, you can use a greeting such as "Hello," with no title combined with formal phrasing in the body of the email.

Should you work in the rare call center where a bit of whimsy is allowed, you can use "gentlefolk" for a non-gendered plural, but this should be used with care.

Comment: In what way should 'gentlefolk' be used with care? Under what contexts do you think it appropriate/inappropriate?

Comment: If I heard someone on the phone calling me "gentlefolk", I would immediately hang up. So I don't think it qualifies for a call-center setting. Unless you call center is in Pacific Standard or Vox.

Comment: I don't see "gentlefolk" as an alternative to "Sir or Madam" ( which is acceptable in print but not in speech) because "gentlefolk" is plural. "Gentlefolk" is the non-gendered equivalent of "Ladies and Gentlemen" (not of "Sir or Madam"). If you must use an archaeism then "gentleperson" might work but it would risk alienating people like @Mitch and myself because it's so pretentious.

Answer (score -1):

Merriam-Webster gives gender neutral title as "Mx" https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/mx-gender-neutral-title

So does [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mx). There is an mp3 there, demonstrating how to pronounce/use in speech.