# phrase request-Talking in completely irrelevant terms to cover up one's lack of knowledge

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Imagine the following scenario:

Charlie walks into a chess club, where Alice and Bob are playing a casual chess game.

Alice: Hi Charlie, do you think I should move the rook or the bishop?

Charlie: According to the Heideggerian phenomenology, chess is a process of *Seinsvergessenheit* which involves an individual's *Existenzialien*. (Blah Blah Blah) therefore there is no such a thing as 'should' and the concept of 'move' is also undefined. Also, there is no difference between a rook and a bishop.

We will suppose here that Charlie does NOT know the strategies of chess game (or any philosophy at all) and is talking in terms of philosophy (which I, personally, I admit, am not acquainted with but nonetheless genuinely respect) only to cover up his lack of knowledge. (The Heidegger stuff is just some random nonsense I put up as an example of what might be involved in this tirade.)

What is a word that can be used to describe Charlie's action in this scenario?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I'd say "He's talking Stack Exchange."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say his remarks are ***[obfuscatory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obfuscatory)***; he's engaging in deliberate obfuscation.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to pronounce that. ob-fuh-SKATE-uh-ree or ob-FUS-kuh-tor-ee? Both are embarrassing.

Comment: @Mitch - Oh, you're not meant to *say* it, it's strictly for written obfuscation (-:

Answer (score 5):

[bluffing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bluff) (or one of its synonyms)

> verb
>   1.   try to deceive someone as to one's abilities or intentions.    "he's been bluffing all along"   synonyms:    pretend, sham, fake, feign,
>   put on an act, put it on, lie, hoax,   pose, posture, masquerade,
>   dissemble, dissimulate;
>   Oxford Dictionaries

[bullshitting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bullshit)

> to ​try to ​persuade someone or make them ​admire you by saying things
>   that are not ​true:   You're bullshitting me!   Quit bullshitting,
>   will you!
>   Cambridge Dictionaries Online

---

As the question specifically mention chess, you may be interested in this publication.

[The Bluffer's Guide to Chess: Bluff Your Way in Chess (Bluffer Guides) Paperback – Nov 1993 By Brian Malpass](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Bluffers-Guide-Chess-Bluffer/dp/185304654X)

Answer (score 2):

***He's talking applesauce***, i.e. spilling irrelevant flim flam to get a grip on things he has no or little knowledge of.

> applesauce: (*North American Informal*) nonsense [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/applesauce)

Alternately, consider ***he's baffling them with bull***.

> *If you can't dazzle them with brilliance, baffle them with bull*. W. C. Fields [Brainy Quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/wcfields108794.html#kiquoEpAqmT3efc7.99)
>
> "Bull", meaning nonsense, dates from the 17th century, while the
>   term "bullshit" has been used as early as 1915 in American slang,
>   and came into popular usage only during World War II. The word "bull"
>   itself may have derived from the Old French boul meaning "fraud,
>   deceit". The term "horseshit" is a near synonym. The South African
>   English equivalent is "bull dust".
>
> The earliest attestation mentioned by the Concise Oxford English
>   Dictionary is in fact T. S. Eliot, who between 1910 and 1916 wrote an
>   early poem to which he gave the title "The Triumph of Bullshit",
>   written in the form of a ballade. The word bullshit does not appear in
>   the text of the poem, and Eliot himself never published the poem.[3]
>
> As to earlier etymology the Oxford English Dictionary cites bull with
>   the meaning "trivial, insincere, untruthful talk or writing,
>   nonsense". It describes this usage as being of unknown origin, but
>   notes that in Old French, the word could mean "boul, boule, bole
>   fraud, deceit, trickery; mod. Icel bull 'nonsense'; also ME bull BUL
>   'falsehood', and BULL verb, to befool, mock, cheat."
>
> Although there is no confirmed etymological connection, it should be
>   noted that these older meanings are synonymous with the modern
>   expression "bull", generally considered and used as a contraction of
>   "bullshit" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit)

Answer (score 2):

The person is being [logorrheic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logorrheic), derived from the noun *logorrhea* meaning

> 1. pathologically incoherent, repetitious speech.
> 2. incessant or compulsive talkativeness; wearisome volubility.
>      <sub>Dictionary.com</sub>

OR **bloviate**

> verb: Talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way. E.g.
>
> - *Until this is corrected, a president and secretary of state [bloviating](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bloviate) about freedom and democracy is received by the rest of the world as mere window-dressing.*
>     <sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The person deliberately chooses obscure terms in order to mislead; prevaricate or hedge.

> **[equivocate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/equivocate#equivocate__2)** (verb)
>   Use **ambiguous** language so as to **conceal the truth** or avoid committing oneself:
>
> - *The law students squirmed and equivocated to avoid confronting my question*
>     <sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

OR

The person is an  **[ultracrepidarian](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268505/44619)**, a person who speaks at length about a subject without having any real knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

One related U.S. English phrase that I sometimes hear is "talking through [one's] hat." Here is the entry for that phrase in Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997):

> **talk through one's hat** Talk nonsense; also, hold forth about something one knows very little about. For example, *He was talking through his hat when he described the shipwreck*, or *Mother went on and on about various screwdrivers but in fact she was talking through her hat*. The allusion in this idiom makes no sense either, which may be the point. {Late 1800s}

Answer (score 0):

He uses **a pseudo-scientific jargon covering up his [own] incompetence**.

> "Jargon" definition: unintelligible or meaningless talk or writing; gibberish;
>   any talk or writing that one does not understand; language that is characterized by uncommon or pretentious vocabulary and convoluted syntax and is often vague in meaning.
>
> To "cover up" means to hide or screen from view or knowledge; conceal.
>   For example, he tried to cover up his mistakes.
>
> "Incompetence" is lack of the ability or knowledge to succesfully
>   carry out a task.

Answer (score 0):

There are two that fit best:

"**He's talking gibberish.**"  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gibberish?s=t (Meaningless or unintelligible talk or writing.)

"**He saying a bunch of mumbo jumbo.**"  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mumbo-jumbo?s=t (Senseless or pretentious language, usually designed to obscure an issue, confuse a listener or the like.)

Comment: Tough crowd! (but then again “tough anonymous down-voting” is clearly oxymoronic, not to mention moronic, so maybe it’s not so tough after all) Regardless, +1 for “xxx-ing gibberish,” which is what first came to my mind (although I’d probably have paired it with “spouting” instead of “talking").

Answer (score -2):

'to blind someone with science'

> blind somebody with science  (British & Australian)
>    if you blind
>   someone with science, you confuse them by using technical language that they are not likely to understand
>   I think he decided to blind us
>   with science because he didn't want us asking any difficult questions.
>   [theFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blind+with+science)

Comment: And this has been downvoted why? This means *exactly* what the OP is asking for. Would someone care to explain?