# What (if anything) is the difference between bullsh— and horsesh—?

Tags: offensive-language

Both *bullshit* and *horseshit* are used to mean nonsense or waffle, especially to cover up a lack of knowledge or unwillingness to inform.

An [old answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/282560/48571) describes them as *near* synonyms. If they're not exact synonyms, what's the difference in meaning or usage?

While *bullshit* may be shortened to *bull*, I've never seen *horse* used to mean nonsense. Perhaps this is just that *horseshit* isn't common enough to be obvious when the *shit* is elided. If the *horse* variant is just variation for added colour, are there others in regular use with very similar meanings? They're certainly not common if so.

In British English, *bullshit*, as well as being a noun, can be a verb (and occasionally an adjective as in a *bullshit excuse*). *Horseshit* on the other hand only appears as a noun (I inadvertently gave an example in the comments).

By coincidence, the blog *Strong Language* posted ["a matrix of shits"](https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2017/11/07/a-matrix-of-shits/) since I wrote this.  It doesn't answer my question, but does illustrate it.

Comment: I'd forgotten about the latter term but was reminded by [a tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/EffinBirds/status/926207472804749313). I know the latter is preferred for fertilising roses, I'm interested in the linguistic use.

Comment: This is a personal opinion, which is why it's a comment and not an answer, but I tend to think of _horseshit_ as being merely inaccurate or mistaken whereas _bullshit_ carries implications of a deliberate intention to mislead or confuse. Anyone agree?

Comment: @BoldBen that's an interesting hypothesis. If would be hard to prove as it relies on proving intent: "I wasn't bullshitting you, just talking horseshit". The tweet I linked in my earlier comment seemed *to me* to refer to a deliberate attempt to mislead but that's a matter of opinion (and context, which of course isn't up to the user on twitter)

Comment: There's definitely such a thing as a chickenshit excuse.

Comment: @StevenLittman, that's a good point, but *chickenshit* is defined as *worthless or contempible* so it's not really the same (though closer than *apeshit*).

Comment: @BoldBen: I see your point but I disagree about the finer points. If someone is unknowingly preaching things that are plain wrong or incoherent, I would dismiss them as bullshit (but you would call it horseshit, if I understand you correctly). I would call it horseshit only if it _is coherent yet not meaningful to the discussion_. Bullshit = knowingly wrong, incoherent or baseless. Horseshit = technically correct but missing the overall point or drawing the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @flater I don't think horseshit is necessarily coherent, just inaccurate. Mostly I was trying to say that bullshit is, to me, deliberately intended to cover up incompetence, deceive the listener or confuse the issue which, to my understanding, is not the case with horseshit. However I'm British and we don't use the word horseshit much, so I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardly any two words are "exact synonyms". Each pair has its differentiating connotations. To me *bullshit* is stronger and more coarse, probably because horses are gentler animals and have been discovered to possess an amazing ability to intuit human feelings (e.g., of their owners).

Anyway, the only real difference I can find is that *horseshit* is marked in dictionaries  as North American or US slang (see the ODO, the OED, and Green's Dictionary of Slang) whereas *bullshit* is not. (*Bullshit* originated as US slang but is no longer marked as such.) They both mean *nonsense*. Or as adjectives *contemptible, offensive, worthless*.
  Green's provides an example of *Horses!* as an exclamation of nonsense.

As verbs, both mean *to talk nonsense* or  *to flatter*.

Comment: Funnily enough I meant to come back and say I'm not aware of *horseshit* as a verb -- an I'm in Britain.  That tends to agree with this answer

Comment: I've never heard *horseshit* used as a verb (AmE, here).

Comment: Horseshit is also excellent for feeding plants. That’s actually what I would think of first if I hear the word.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer on this one, but less formal resources than the print dictionary seem to agree with my impression that "horse--" is more emotionally charged and focuses more on a situation that is abusive or unjust.

[Urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=horse%20shit) sense 2 has:

> as opposed to bullshit, which expresses judgement on shallow, insensible, and false ideas, horseshit puts more emphasis on the speaker's distress about the message just received

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horseshit) sense 1 has:

> Serious harassment or abuse

(As a methodological side note, I'd argue that when looking for the definitions of expletives, community sources or less-official sources often have more current and nuanced information than publication-ready dictionaries.)

Essentially, there are two meanings with which bull-- or horse-- are used. For bull--, the more prominent one is "something said without regard for whether it is true or false, in which the speaker has no sincere belief." However, a secondary meaning is "unfair treatment or an unjust situation" (which you'll see contextually from [a google search for sports](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=that+ref%27s+call+was+bullshit)). This meaning is especially invoked when used with an intensifier, "f--g bull--".

My impression--and others would seem to agree, see [a blog posting about the distinction in which a commenter succinctly argues](https://uncomelyandbroken.com/2012/03/17/horseshit-versus-bullshit-2/#comment-5735) "Bull[] is something that is not true and horse[] is a situation that is unfair"--that for horse--, the secondary and primary meanings are reversed. With horse--, the "unfairness" meaning is prioritized, even though it can also be used for bull--'s primary meaning of statements said for convenience rather than truth.

[Here's another contextual usage example](https://www.defendingbigd.com/2019/2/22/18236835/fucking-horseshit-jim-lites-t-shirt-dallas-stars-hockey-shirts-bunch-of-jerks-puns-jokes-nhl-shirts): this is a T-shirt which has the choice pull quote, "F--g horse--", from the CEO of the Dallas Stars, a hockey team; contextually, he was reacting to the 2018-2019 season, during which two very highly compensated players were under-performing. Horse-- conveys a greater sense of disgust, and can do so just fine on its own; see [its use in Titanic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP7DYbjIIJ4), in a scene in which Leonardo DiCaprio's character Jack is reacting with anger and disbelief to being framed for grand larceny--the actor's line delivery is typical of the greater emotional charge.

---

Similarly, as of the morning of June 10 2021, here are the top 10 hits for a Google News search for the term "bull--":

1. Why the bull--jobs thesis may be, well, bull--
2. 'This Is Some Bull--': Women's Group Rails Against Biden Inaction on Equal Rights Amendment
3. Nation Rocked By 40 Million Acts of Total Bull-- (The Onion)
4. "They talk about national sentiment, but that's bull--"
5. Book Review: 'Calling Bull--' will help you be a better advocate
6. Fox Business Host Rolls Over When Trump Spews Election Bull--
7. Katt Williams Thoughtfully Explains Why The Cancel Culture Narrative is Bull--
8. The bull- jobs theory may turn out to be, well, bull- (second source reporting on the same study)
9. How to Tell If Your Company's Pride Campaign Is Bull--
10. Brooks Koepka lost his train of thought hearing [someone's] bull--

Of these, headlines 2 and 3 are used in the sense of "unfairness," while the rest are used in the sense of "false or nonsense statements."

By comparison, the top 10 hits in Google News for 'horse--' are:

1. QAnon's cowboy-themed "Patriot Roundup" sure sounds like it was full of horse--
2. Farmers Only: Dayton comes back from huge deficit. [from blurb, "Brantley 'Ding Dong' Bell singled, walked twice, and scored three runs while Aristides 'Horse--' Aquino has turned into a walk machine"]
3. After Wednesday's blowout, the Orioles June magic is on hold, for now [from blurb, "Harvey himself said to reporters, 'It's been a couple years now of being really horse--'."]
4. The horse-- paradox: Why fears about tech are wildly exaggerated
5. Your Apple AirTag can't say horse-- but it can say poop horse
6. Samantha Bee Says We Need To Strangle The Filibuster to Death [From blurb, "It's horse--", referring to the filibuster being unjust]
7. Prison Break Season 6 canceled but why are fans applauding the decision? [Blurb: "Another user comment: 'Season 5 was complete horse--, so I'm glad there's no season 6 to be honest'"]
8. Thoughts on a 4-2 Rangers loss [Blurb: "Gallo having homered earlier in the inning, was a horse-- call... I mean, that's horse--"]
9. Cut after 31 minutes: Heal on the outer after shocking move [Blurb: "then cutting a 19yo for lack of experience is horse-- as a GM, as a coach, as an organization and even more so, as human beings"]
10. In Leaked Video, Mayor Garcetti Compares Unhoused People to Horse--

Of these, only hit 1 refers to "something false or nonsensical".
Hits 2 and 7 probably mean "something worthless" (one of them being used as a nickname--I don't know if this was the writer being cute or if it's actually used, baseball is weird). Hits 4 and 10 refer to literal horse excrement, hit 5 referred to the word "horse--", and hits 3, 6, 8, and 9 are referring to an unfair or unjust situation.

Comment: Please include the quotes/examples you are citing or their transcriptions to make your answer more self-contained and to avoid link rot.  Thanks and welcome to EL&U.