# What's the word for a person who possesses extensive vocabulary?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Verbose* or *wordy* do not serve the purpose as intended, as both are used negatively.

*Articulate* or *well-spoken*, in my opinion, do not do justice also, as somebody could have smaller lexicon pool, yet still be fluent in their expression.

Thence, I cannot consider my query as a duplicate of the other.

Please help, & thank you!

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268505/2085). :-)

Comment: It may be a good possibility that I appear slow for mentioning this. But, I fail to find the relation. :-| @tchrist

Comment: The title of your question says "extensive vocabulary." But you contradict yourself in the edit to the body of the question by saying "somebody could have smaller lexicon pool." So, which is it? What are you actually asking? (Also note that you can quite easily be *articulate* or *well-spoken* even with a small vocabulary.)