# What is an idiom for an ultracrepidarian?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for a person who is in the habit of giving advice or suggestions on matters he or she knows nothing about? I know there is this word *ultracrepidarian* for such people but I'm looking for an idiom.A phrase would do too.

Comment: When asking a question you're supposed to be a bit more specific about what context you're going to use the word in and what exactly you're referring to. There are various terms for educated people who exceed their areas of expertise, but different terms for idiots who know nothing but think they know everything, or for those who like to contribute to every conversation without necessarily professing expertise. Are you looking for an adjectival phrase, a noun phrase, an address to such people ("cobbler, stick to your last" is allegedly something people say), or what?

Comment: Searching for *ultracrepidarian* on this site will lead one to several pages where arguable synonyms for this word may be found. (The question itself is not a duplicate in the strict sense, but it is a duplicate in a broad sense, in so far as likely answers to it will repeat what can be found on these other pages.)

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268505/2085).

Answer (score 2):

I make three suggestions (***meddler*** and the more idiomatic ***backseat driver*** and ***busybody***) but in confirming them have found others I did not know previously:

> *meddler* - an officious annoying person who interferes with others
> an unwelcome person, persona non grata - a person who for some reason is not wanted or welcome
>
> *backseat driver* - a meddler who insists on giving unwanted advice
>
> *busybody*, *nosey-parker*, *nosy-parker*, *quidnunc* - a person who meddles in the affairs of others
>
> *buttinsky* - a meddler who tends to butt in
>
> *kibitzer* - (Yiddish) a meddler who offers unwanted advice to others
>
> [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meddler#:%7E:text=Noun-,1.,meddles%20in%20the%20affairs%20of)

Other dictionaries are consistent with this conveniently compact group of descriptions.

Comment: I know plenty of "armchair experts".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey a good addition to the list!

Answer (score 1):

A term denoting such a person, that (unlike *ultracrepidarian*) would be readily understood by most English speakers, is *know-it-all*. In British English, its variant *know-all* is also available. The term is inherently ironic: it means that the person does not, in fact, know very much, let alone 'all', but merely behaves as if he does.

Comment: This is posted as a wiki-answer because it is a copy of what appears in an answer that I have posted to a differently formulated, but closely related question.