# Is there a precise word for "affecting greater knowledge than one actually possesses?"

Tags: single-word-requests

*Pretension* immediately comes to mind, *pedantry* is close but there isn't the element of being wrong in the "display of learning," and *posturing* and *sophistry* have been suggested but both contain an unwanted degree of malice.

Comment: Our guidelines say that for single word requests you need to provide an example sentence where the word would be used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The [accepted answer at the linked duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268505/2085) starting out “Cryptonescient Morosophs and Ultracrepidarians” should lead you quickly to conclude that you're talking about [*ultracrepidarianism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutor,_ne_ultra_crepidam), but in the unexpected event that should somehow avoid hitting the nail on the head, there are plenty of related terms mentioned there from which you might derive one more to your liking.

Comment: I'm not sure why my previous comment was deleted.  It's a perfectly good word that describes the concept asked. It might be a slightly rude word,  but c'mon.  It's the 2020s, not the fifties.

Comment: @tchrist I was looking for a verb (and this lack of clarity is my own fault) but what you've given me is quite satisfying as is. Thanks :)