# Is there a word for "opinionated" that isn't a negative attribute?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Introduction: … and this is the opinionated Mr. Smith.

"Opinionated" seems like the word I want to use, but it and its synonyms all seem to have negative denotations or connotations.

Is there a *nice* word (or very short phrase) to describe someone that has a considerable general knowledge and experience, and is able, whenever asked, to offer an opinion on almost any topic?

UPDATE: The answers so far are close, but miss the idea that the person *enjoys* giving his opinions and ideas (but does so only in appropriate circumstances).
In terms of real people, I'd say Isaac Asimov would be a good example.
He was knowledgeable (or could quickly become so) on any topic, and never missed an opportunity to provide an opinion.
(And no, I don't want "Asimovian" as the answer.)

Comment: The problem with opinionated is that it reflects rigidity, not knowledge. Being stuck on your opinions does not even reflect education.

Comment: There may well be such words, but *opinionated* is not one of them, if you accept the major definitions (Merriam-Webster, Cambridge, Collins, Free Dictionary, ... ).

Comment: I came up with *well informed* but that's two words.  If OP wants a single word, I'll think a little harder, if OP might be satisfied by two I'll write an answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, two words would be okay, but "*well informed*" isn't what I want. The person *wants* to expound, and it's generally welcome by whoever's listening or reading.  I started with "opinionated" because the person always has an opinion about everything, but that word is negative and I want a positive feel.

Comment: Ahh, well you obviously want *well informative* then :-)

Comment: You want someone who enjoys giving their opinion but won't do so unless forced to? Seems like a strange person. If you came across someone who really likes playing football but won't do so voluntarily, wouldn't you think they were odd?

Comment: @StuartF "*won't do so unless forced to?*" — no, not *forced* to. The slightest encouragement would do, but with enough sense to realize that not everyone automatically wants to hear someone else's opinion (no matter how brilliant it might be).

Comment: Regardless of whether you find the right word or phrase I don't think it's normal to introduce people with a description of their demeanor. What if the person chose to be the bad version of opinionated after your introduction?

Comment: Just imagine trying to introduce someone to your parents as "This is John and they don't give their opinion unless they're asked." Also take into account that not everyone places the same value on any given personality. A pleasing personality to one is weak and uninteresting to another. You're pigeon-holing this person before they're ever allowed to give a first impression.

Comment: Interestingly, in the field of software engineering, "opinionated" has shed its negative connotation. Instead, it has evolved into a jargon adjective that can be applied to computer programs, such as "an opinionated file manager". In this usage, the file manager program might be "opinionated" in that it offers relatively few configuration options, or is designed around a specific workflow.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I think I'm ready to give up on the English language (or at least it's given up on me in the last few years).  It took me far too long to figure out that sentence; "… your parents … they don't … ." made very little sense.

Answer (score 5):

"Opinionated" means someone who's eager to give their strong opinions on topics, often without being asked for them, and generally implies the person forms their opinions easily, without getting sufficient information. So it's probably closer to the opposite of what you're looking for.

If you want the word for someone who knows what they're talking about and is likely to offer valuable insight and/or suggest a good course of action, the words you're looking for may be "**knowledgeable**" or "**erudite**".

> **Knowledgable:** having or showing knowledge or intelligence

> **Erudite:** having or showing knowledge that is gained by studying

(Both definitions from Merriam Webster)

Comment: I don't think that those words quite work... You can have strong (but incorrect opinions) without being opinionated as long as you're not an arsehole about it. That being said, "erudite" is a quality word.

Answer (score 3):

You just "**have strong opinions**".

There's nothing wrong with having strong opinions, even if they turn out to be incorrect. You only become "opinionated" if you're a bit of an arsehole about it, proffer your opinions without them being wanted and aren't even willing to consider contradictory information.

To give an example:

Take a Christian who believes the world is 6000 years old, that dinosaurs aren't real and that evolution by natural selection isn't a thing.

Let's assume they've had a good education and been shown all of the evidence that indisputably proves that the world is billions of years old, dinosaurs were real, and natural selection is how things are done. If, after all of that, they're still going around telling everyone they're wrong, that biology textbooks should teach intelligent design, and that dinosaurs are a hoax. Then, they're opinionated.

If, however, they haven't been shown all of that evidence, and aren't going around telling everyone else that they're wrong, then they're just someone with some strong, but incorrect, opinions.

I don't think I agree with most of the other answers that require your opinions to be based on some sort of underlying knowledge, I genuinely believe it's more about the arsehole factor.

Apologies for some of the language in this answer, but I really can't think of a better way to put it that concisely conveys my meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who "has a considerable general knowledge and experience" can be described in a positive way to be

> **worldly-wise**
>
> experienced in the ways in which people behave and able to deal with most situations

from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worldly-wise).

Answer (score 0):

You could call them a **sophisticate,** [defined by Wiktionary as](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophisticate):

> A person who is sophisticated (“experienced in the ways of the world, that is, cosmopolitan or worldly-wise”), or who has sophisticated tastes.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to home in on the right word— if there exists one— for such a person. A person with an excessive interest in their own opinions is called a **philodox**, but the word carries potentially pejorative connotations.

Since the poster is looking for a "*nice*" word, I think he might consider this adjective: **well-rounded**

Per *Cambridge Dictionary*:

> involving or having experience in a wide range of ideas or activities:

[ *before noun* ] *She describes herself as a "well-rounded individual" who works hard but has a varied social life.*

Comment: Oh nice, this is the second appearance of *philodox* on our site! [Here’s the first](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268505/2085).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a word that suggests the person has knowledge. As mentioned in other answers, "opinionated" suggests the person may lack knowledge.

If so, I'd suggest "erudite", "learned", or "knowledgeable".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a nice word (or very short phrase) to describe someone that has a considerable general knowledge and experience, and is able, whenever asked, to offer an opinion on almost any topic?

A **Fount of (all) Knowledge**

although this is often used sarcastically, to describe someone who is too keen to offer opinions, or offers wrong ones

I am reminded of the irregular verb conjugation for a similar characteristic

- I am strong-willed
- You are stubborn
- They are bloody-minded

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "discriminating", as in *discriminating tastes*.  You have to be careful of your context so it doesn't come across like "discriminatory"; but overall this seems to fit the bill.

> He is a discriminating film buff

To my ear it indicates a person who is knowledgeable of a subject, and has clear opinions, and would be willing to talk about it if asked; but not necessarily insisting on spouting off all the time to others.

Answer (score 0):

The closest word I can think of is "eristic". While it has certainly been used as a pejorative, I've also seen it used more generally as meaning "fond of debate".

"Scrappy" and "pugnacious" also have positive connotations, but are more specific in that they imply a defiance against someone/something more powerful (so, a thinker that often disputes prevailing wisdom might be pugnacious). As such, I don't think they fit your question.

Lastly, you could use a phrase like, "[x] is fond of debate" without too negative of a connotation. Alternatively "disposed to" also works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).