# Neologism meaning "Having-an-opinion-despite-having-no-idea-what-you're-talking-about"

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember encountering a word (it was a neologism, not a popularly accepted word) that meant something like "having-a-strong-but-completely-uninformed-opinion". It might have been the related idea of "arguing-vehemently-without-really-knowing-what-you're-talking-about".

I wanted to use this word recently (political climate, doncha know), but couldn't (and can't) remember it.  Can anyone help me recall?

---

Example usage (pretty sure it was an adj):

> Geez, the commenter on that thread is so ________.

Comment: Like something between _opinion nazi_ and [_opinioneering_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=opinioneering)?

Comment: (Hardline) Fundamentalist?

Comment: Usually *talking out of one's ass* or some synonymous phrase.

Comment: I almost just want to say "having an [opinion](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/opinion)" based upon Noah Webster's definition of the word given in The American Dictionary of the English Language but that is not a neologism and it's based upon weak evidence, rather than no evidence. I suppose this isn't really an opinion if "completely uninformed" isn't just hyperbolic though.

Comment: He is such a **blather**.

Comment: *talking through one's hat* (British, informal)

Comment: *clueless yet opinionated*

Comment: It's not exactly a neologism, but it is a very rare word, it means to proffer an opinion on a subject which is beyond your  knowledge or competance  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251797/word-for-someone-ignorant-of-but-not-expected-to-be-knowledgeable-about-someth/252001#252001 The adjective would be *ultracrepidarian*

Comment: "Pulling a Trump."

Comment: Good answer, Senex.  But I think the simple answer is just opinionated.  Despite its possible neutral connotation, I think in most situations, it's used to mean "always having an opinion, regardless of the facts."

Comment: @Steven Littman \\ Thanks. This just in: "Trump took to Twitter on Sunday to comment on the issue [Will's departure from the GOP], calling Will 'one of the most overrated political pundits.' Will fired back, saying that Trump 'has an advantage on me because he can say everything he knows about any subject in 140 characters and I can’t.'"

Comment: As Trump has already come up, there's been some very eloquent and creative insults directed at him by the Scottish on his recent visit - terms like _blowhard_ and _bloviating_ seem like they may get close to the single-word mark. Have a look on twitter for the full catalogue...

Comment: Usually, my friends refer to the behaviour as "Being Stan."

Comment: The answer to this question is "*Brexit".